# Javascript countdown timer logic

Tags: javascript, timer, logic

I'm having a bit of trouble with the logic here:

```
var seccount=60;
var seccounter=setInterval(sectimer, 1000);
function sectimer() {
  seccount=seccount-1;
  if (seccount < 0) {
    seccount=59;
    return;
}
document.getElementById("sectimer").innerHTML=seccount+ " seconds!";
```

When this gets down to 0, the timer stays at 0 for 2 seconds and then jumps to 58 again. I have tried a few different things in the function, such as:

```
function sectimer() {
  seccount=seccount-1;
  if (seccount <= 0) {
    seccount=59;
    return;
}
```

and

```
function sectimer() {
  seccount=seccount-1;
  if (seccount < 1) {
    seccount=60;
    return;
}
```

but everything has some variation where the timer freezes at some number for 2 seconds and then goes to the number I chose.

What am I missing?

Comment: return; causes the function to exit before the ui is updated, so the ui is not updated to display 59 and skips to 58 on the next interval.

Comment: Thanks! Between your comment and Slavik's answer, I got everything I needed: a solution and an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return is misplaced. Try this:

```
var seccount=60;
var seccounter=setInterval(sectimer, 1000);
function sectimer() {
    seccount--;
    if (seccount < 0) {
        seccount=59;
    }
    document.getElementById("sectimer").innerHTML=seccount+ " seconds!";
}
```

The `return` caused the function to be terminated immediately, therefor, when it enters into the condition `if (seccount < 0)` (in case the `seccount` is `-1`), the `seccount` is being updated to be `59` and then it never reaches the element update below, but terminates on `return`. Then, the next time it runs after a second, the `seccount` is drops to `58` which is clearly not lower than zero, and skips into the element update row. That's why you feel like you lost 2 seconds, because you skipped one time of element update :-)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Why would the return cause this though? And why is the return not needed? Thanks a lot! EDIT: @Kenji answered above. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i might do this as follows;

```js
function countDownFrom(n,lim = n){
  result.textContent = n + " seconds";
  setTimeout(countDownFrom,1000,n ? --n : lim-1,lim);
}
countDownFrom(5);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```